# How can I set Slurm Partition QoS?

Tags: partition, slurm, qos, sbatch

I created partition QOS to my Slurm partition but it isn't worked. How can I solve this problem. If anyone knows, please let me know.  The following steps are my operation.

1. CreateQoS

```
$sacctmgr show qos format="Name,MaxWall,MaxTRESPerUser%30,MaxJob,MaxSubmit,Priority,Preempt"
```

```
Name       MaxWall                          MaxTRESPU MaxJobs MaxSubmit   Priority    Preempt 
---------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------- --------- ---------- ---------- 
    normal                                                                   0            
batchdisa+                                               0         0         10
```

2.Attach QOS to partition

```
$scontrol show partition
```

```
PartitionName=sample01
   AllowGroups=ALL AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL
   AllocNodes=ALL Default=YES QoS=batchdisable
   DefaultTime=NONE DisableRootJobs=NO ExclusiveUser=NO GraceTime=0 Hidden=NO
   MaxNodes=UNLIMITED MaxTime=UNLIMITED MinNodes=0 LLN=NO MaxCPUsPerNode=UNLIMITED
   Nodes=computenode0[1-2]
   PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 RootOnly=NO ReqResv=NO OverSubscribe=NO
   OverTimeLimit=NONE PreemptMode=OFF
   State=UP TotalCPUs=2 TotalNodes=2 SelectTypeParameters=NONE
   JobDefaults=(null)
   DefMemPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxMemPerNode=UNLIMITED
```

3.Run Jobs

```
squeue
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
          67109044    sample01  testjob test  R       1:42      1 computenode01
          67109045    sample01  testjob test  R       1:39      1 computenode02
```

Comment: How did you create partition qos? Unsue what the right command is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following setting to slrum.conf.

```
AccountingStorageEnforce=associations
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).